# highlight certain entries in bibliography using natbib

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

I would like to highlight (for example by **) certain entries in my bibliography, which are more significant. I would also prefer if I could write brief remarks below the appropriate entry. For example,

** Dow, Joe. Topics in oriental cooking. Nat. Rev. Cuis. 2018

(indent) **This is a very interesting paper discussing many things.**

Could someone show me how to do this?

Comment: I think the easiest way would be to recover the .bst  file (produce by the command bibtex) and change the entries "by hand".

Comment: @ Mico -- yes, my bad, it's the .bbl file!